# LIBSVM Evaluation with F-Score, Precision or Recall

Tags: python, libsvm

I am new to Libsvm, and I just tried doing cross validation using grid.py and it gave me only accuracy evaluation.

How do I make it show F-Score (preferred), or Precision and Recall?

Thanks!

Comment: can't you use sklearn? http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authors of `libsvm` have provided [an extension](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/eval/index.html) which enables you to use different scoring mechanisms during cross-validation, depending on your needs. Currently, it supports `precision`, `recall`, `fscore`, `bac` and `auc`.

Unfortunately, setting it up does involve a bit of manual work, so, if you need any help, please let me know.